# Cannot read GPS position from photo

Tags: metadata, gps

I cannot get GPS position from [this photo](https://e.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZdDyVZwG52sqdpQPby7ioEkIByvYN8splX)

exiftool show:

```
  | 8)  GPSInfo (SubDirectory) -->
  |     - Tag 0x8825 (4 bytes, int32u[1]):
  |         007e: 00 00 15 fe                                     [....]
  | + [GPS directory with 9 entries]
  | | 0)  GPSLatitudeRef = 
  | |     - Tag 0x0001 (2 bytes, string[2]):
  | |         1614: 00 00                                           [..]
  | | 1)  GPSLatitude = undef undef undef (0/0 0/0 0/0)
  | |     - Tag 0x0002 (24 bytes, rational64u[3]):
  | |         167c: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 [................]
  | |         168c: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                         [........]
  | | 2)  GPSLongitudeRef = 
  | |     - Tag 0x0003 (2 bytes, string[2]):
  | |         162c: 00 00                                           [..]
  | | 3)  GPSLongitude = undef undef undef (0/0 0/0 0/0)
  | |     - Tag 0x0004 (24 bytes, rational64u[3]):
  | |         1694: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 [................]
  | |         16a4: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                         [........]
  | | 4)  GPSAltitudeRef = 0
  | |     - Tag 0x0005 (1 bytes, int8u[1]):
  | |         1644: 00                                              [.]
  | | 5)  GPSAltitude = undef (0/0)
  | |     - Tag 0x0006 (8 bytes, rational64u[1]):
  | |         16ac: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                         [........]
  | | 6)  GPSTimeStamp = undef undef undef (0/0 0/0 0/0)
  | |     - Tag 0x0007 (24 bytes, rational64u[3]):
  | |         16b4: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 [................]
  | |         16c4: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                         [........]
  | | 7)  GPSProcessingMethod = 
  | |     - Tag 0x001b (12 bytes, undef[12]):
  | |         16cc: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00             [............]
  | | 8)  GPSDateStamp = 
  | |     - Tag 0x001d (11 bytes, string[11] read as undef[11]):
  | |         16d8: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                [...........]
  | Warning = Tag ID 0x011a XResolution out of sequence in IFD0
  | 9)  XResolution = 72 (72/1)
  |     - Tag 0x011a (8 bytes, rational64u[1]):
  |         00ca: 00 00 00 48 00 00 00 01                         [...H....]
  | 10) YResolution = 72 (72/1)
  |     - Tag 0x011b (8 bytes, rational64u[1]):
  |         00d2: 00 00 00 48 00 00 00 01                         [...H....]
  | Warning = Tag ID 0x010f Make out of sequence in IFD0
  | 11) Make = Xiaomi
  |     - Tag 0x010f (7 bytes, string[7]):
  |         00da: 58 69 61 6f 6d 69 00                            [Xiaomi.]
```

But in buildin gallery (MIUI) I can see GPS data. Can anyone help me fix this (preferebly by some automated way to rewrite data to be readable)

If this helps - photo was taken with POCO F2 Pro (MIUI default camera)

Comment: GPS tags are present, but their value is 0 (zero). How do you get the photos out of the phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've looked at your photograph and it really does seem like the GPS data is being zeroed out, i.e. stripped, from the image as it is being exported from your phone. If you can only see the image GPS information in the built-in image viewer tool, is it possible that the built-in tool is accessing a different version of the image file?

Answer (score 2):

Well... It occured that i have automatic upload of photos to cloud. Somehow, for some reason - it removes (at least GPS data). Im really sorry for bothering You all - and I have spent definicely too much time today trying to find GPS data within files where it does not exists...

Answer (score 0):

The GPS data can be very revealing (they can give your address for instance) so for safety many applications now remove them.

- On my Android phone, this is an option (set by default) in the Photo Gallery app where GPS data are removed when the photo is sent out using the application's "Share" function (which is how you usually send things to the cloud or other people: mail, chat, cloud (DropBox for me...).
- On the other hand if I use the DropBox app directly to upload the picture, the GPS data is kept.
- And this isn't the end of the story, many sites where images are made available to the public strip out the GPS data for safety (and there is little you can do about this).